# need some processing to do before cloud function returns a promise. But promise is return before the processing

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i have a cloud function where i pass an array of numbers and compare those numbers with collection in the firestore . And if the numbers are present than return an array with those numbers. But before comparing those numbers the function return empty value in the promise.

I've tried using async await but the execution sequence remained same.

//sort contact list

```
export const  addMessage= functions.https.onCall(async (data:any, context) => {

     const col=admin.firestore().collection("joshua");

     var match:[]
    match=data.list  
      var perm1=new Array()
      res11.push("454675556")
     console.log("above resolve")

        for(let val in match){

        var inter=await Promise.all([getValues(col,val)])
        console.log("inside resolve"+inter)

           }

  perm1.push("23432")
  console.log("just before resolve")

  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      res(perm1)
  })

      });



//the async function which is suppose to process on every iteration

 function getValues(col1:any,val1:any)
       {
         return new Promise(async(res,rej)=>{ 
          var query= await col1.where('Listed','array-contains',val1)
              var value=await query.get()
                res(value)
            })
            .catch(err=>{
              console.log(err)
            })
       }
```

i want the sequence to be asynchronous where the return value from getValues is waited upon and inside getValues result of query.get is waited upon.
so that at last return only be sent when all process is finished.

Comment: You're probably forgot `async` on you `getValues` declaration. But I didn't dive deep in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
export const  addMessage= functions.https.onCall(async (data:any, context) => {

  const col = admin.firestore().collection("joshua");
  var match:[]
  match = data.list  
  var perm1 = []
  // res11.push("454675556") // ? undefined

  for(let val in match){
    var inter = await getValues(col,val)
    console.log("inside resolve" + inter)
  }

  perm1.push("23432") // ??
  // console.log("just before resolve")

  return Promise.resolve(perm1)

});



const getValues = async (col1:any, val1:any) => {
  const query = col1.where('Listed','array-contains', val1)
  var value = await query.get().then(getAllDocs)
  return value
}

const getAllDocs = function(data: any) {
  const temp: Array<any> = []
  data.forEach(function (doc: any) {
    temp.push(doc.data())
  })
  return temp
}
```